# slow cooking vs pressure cook

Tags: slow-cooking, pressure-cooker

What would be the difference if you slow cooked a piece of meat for 8 hours or pressure cooked a piece of meat for a relatively long time of 1.5 hours.  Would they both be tender/soft and taste similar?

Is pressure cooker a substitute for slow cooking if you put a long time?

Answer (score 1):

In pressure cooking, higher temperature are possble given the increased pressure, which greatly reduces cook time.  You can get a similar outcome, especially for proteins that benefit from a longer cook time. In this case, a pressure cooker can be a sort of short cut.  A lot depends on the particular cut of meat and the preparation, but you can certainly achieve tenderness using either method.  Some ingredients behave differently in a pressure cooker.  An example is onions.  Their aromatics and flavor seem to be muted at the high temperature of pressure cookers.  You can compensate by simply using more. In the case of onions, a lot more.  So, there are some adjustments to be made, but similar results can be achieved.

Comment: You also have to adjust for moisture.  A slow cooker recipe is a pressure cooker can be even more muted as the liquids don’t evaporate and reduce.  (But you can’t start it dry and let the meat release juices, either, as you at least some liquid to evaporate and create the pressure)